# In GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor operator, is prefix case-sensitive? If it is then is there some way we can make it case insensitive?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am using the **GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor** operator in order to detect if an object is present in a GCS bucket or not. However, I noticed that the sensor is not able to detect the objects if the case is different. e.g if the prefix I supplied is **ABC**, then it is not able to detect object **Abc.csv**.
Can someone please guide me on what can I do to make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 0):

You may try and consider below approach.

Use **GCSHook** to get the objects on your desired bucket and then filter the objects based on your prefix using *REGEX*.

You may refer to below sample code that I used in my testing:

```py
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook
from airflow.operators import python

import re

bucket_name = 'your-bucket'
my_prefix = '[Aa]+[Bb]+[Cc]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+.(csv|pdf|json)'

array_objects = []

with airflow.DAG(
        'test_delete_dag',
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    
     def get_and_delete_obj():
         hook = GCSHook()
         objects = hook.list(bucket_name=bucket_name)
         
         for obj in objects:
                if re.match(my_prefix,obj):
                    array_objects.append(obj)
         print(array_objects)
        
         for arr in array_objects:
                hook.delete(bucket_name=bucket_name, object_name=arr)

     test_delete = python.PythonOperator(
            task_id='delete_gcs_obj',
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=get_and_delete_obj,
            )

     test_delete
```

Note that in my *REGEX* above, I specify the file extensions as part of my filtering of the object. You may just modify the *REGEX* to match your use case.